# Get integer from Char value and then get %

Tags: java, arraylist, char, character

I try get integer value from char value and then get their %.

Error code throws here

I trie with:

`int tmp = Character.getNumericValue(entradas.get(i).toString().charAt(j)) % i;`

Or rror code throws here

And I trie with:

`int tmp = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(entradas.get(i).toString().charAt(j)));`

Then continuing this:

`if(tmp == 0) suma += Character.getNumericValue(entradas.get(i).toString().charAt(j));`

Comment: What is the error?  What is in entradas?  What values do i and j have?  You need much more detail for anyone to be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

"char" type nearly equals to "int".

You do not have to parse it or getting numeric value for that.

Lets say you have this code:

```
String sample = "abc";
char c = sample.getCharAt(0);
int x = (int) c;
System.out.println(x);
```

That's it.